# Simple background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am trying ot get the background color to change behind a partially transparent .png div.  The class that modifies the div is ".alert".  I can manually edit the .alert class background color, and it works perfectly.  Now I'm just trying to do this one a 1 sec cycle.

I have this:

```
var bgstate = 0;
var states = [];
states[0] = '#F00';
states[1] = '#CCC';
states[2] = '#F00';

function flash() {
bgstate++;
if( bgstate > 2 ) bgstate = 0;

$('.alert').ready(function() {
        $('.alert').css({ 'background-color' : " + states[bgstate] + " 
    });

});


$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(flash, 1000);
});
```

I can't seem to get the "states[x]" to work for the class alert.  I'm very bad at this, and I don't know the correct syntax.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will give you demo :

```
var bg = ["#000","#f00","#ff0"];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if (i < bg.length ) {
    $("body").css({'background-color' :  bg[i] });
    i++;
    }
    else {
     $("body").css({'background-color' :  bg[0] });
    i = 1;
    }
},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9jhX/

Comment: This is a very simple well done version of what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` should be `setInterval`

[setInterval doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Without testing the rest of the code, it looks like you may have a simple syntax error:

```
$('.alert').css({ 'background-color' : " + states[bgstate] + " });
```

You are trying to pass a HEX color value here, which is a string type, however the value inserted above is literal.

Try this (note the additional single-quotes around the states[x] variable):

```
$('.alert').css({ 'background-color' : '" + states[bgstate] + "' });
```

Comment: Admittedly, his pasted example contains syntax errors, but his question is really "given that it works, how do I get it to fire more than once?" not "why doesn't this ever work?"

Answer (score 0):

Not closing your Quotes properly .. Try this

```
$('.alert').css({ 'background-color' : '"' + states[bgstate] + '"'  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a slightly more reusable version:

```
var Flasher = function ( elem, pattern ) {
  this.bg = pattern;
  this.i = 0;
  this.$el = elem;
}

Flasher.prototype.flash = function ( interval ) {
    var self = this;
    this.loop = setInterval( function() {
       if (self.i < self.bg.length) {
            self.$el.css({'background-color' :  self.bg[self.i] });
        }
        else {
         self.i = 0;
         self.$el.css({'background-color' :  self.bg[self.i] });
        }
        self.i++;
    },interval);
};

Flasher.prototype.stop = function () {
  clearInterval(this.loop);
};
var flasher = new Flasher( $('body'), ["#000","#f00","#ccc"] );
flasher.flash(1000);
flasher.stop();
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
var bgstate = 0;
var states = ['#F00','#CCC','#F00'];

function flash() {
 $('.alert').css('background-color', states[bgstate] );
 bgstate = (bgstate+1) % states.length;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(flash, 1000);
});
```